# vb.net datagridview printing error "Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference"

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

```
    Private Sub MyPrintDocument_PrintPage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs)
    Dim more As Boolean

    more = DataGridViewPrinter.DrawDataGridView(e.Graphics)
    If more Then e.HasMorePages = True

End Sub
```

This is my sub and i get the error "Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference" it is a reference to a public class "DataGridViewPrinter" with a public function "DrawDataGridView" can anyone help?

Comment: Since `DrawDataGridView` is not Shared/static, you need to create an instance of `DataGridViewPrinter`

Answer (score 0):

There is no instance of DataGridViewPrinter at the time it is used:

```
more = DataGridViewPrinter.DrawDataGridView(e.Graphics)
```

Maybe initialize it as New, or assign a new instance to it.